# How to make "git merge --log" stop flattening merge commits

Tags: git, merge, feature-branch

I am using [a successful git branching model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), where you have `master` branch only consisting from merge commits with version tags, and all the development goes on `develop` branch.

The `develop` branch also consists of merge commits (feature branches) and ordinary commits (small individual changes).

When I perform a new version release, I want git to make me a chengelog. `git merge develop --log` does this, but this "unrolls" merge commits on `develop`, resulting in a flat history.

I want to make 'git merge --log' use only commits on `develop`, is this possible?

Examples:

What I atually get now when merging:

```
Merge branch 'develop' into master

* develop:
  fix 1 on branch develop
  fix 2 on branch develop
  fix 1 on branch b1
  fix 2 on branch b1
  fix 3 on branch b1
  fix 1 on branch b2
  fix 2 on branch b2
  fix 1 on branch b3
```

What I want it to be:

```
Merge branch 'develop' into master

* develop:
  fix 1 on branch develop
  fix 2 on branch develop
  Merge branch 'b1' into develop
  Merge branch 'b2' into develop
  Merge branch 'b3' into develop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the log you want for an inflight merge, use

```
git log --pretty='  %s' --first-parent ..MERGE_HEAD  # with e.g. `-10` to limit to 10
```

or to see what that'd get from an existing merge use `merge^1..merge^2` as your range.

The quickest way to get to a smoketest is probably `git merge --log=1` to generate the right boilerplate, then in vim it'd be

```
:/^\*/+,+!git log --pretty='  \%s' --first-parent ..MERGE_HEAD
```

to fill in the log the way you want.  To automate it you'll need to use the `prepare-commit-msg` hook, something along the lines of

```
case $2 in
merge)
        git log --pretty='  %s' --first-parent ..MERGE_HEAD >${tempfile=`mktemp`}
        sed -i '/^\*/,/^$/ { //!d }; /^\*/ r '$tempfile  "$1"
        rm $tempfile
        ;;
esac
```

edit: on GNU/anything, the hook gets simpler because the sed's buffier:

```
case $2 in
merge)
        git log --pretty='  %s' --first-parent ..MERGE_HEAD \
        | sed -i '/^\*/,/^$/ { //!d }; /^\*/ r /dev/stdin' "$1"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you! BTW you've forgotten opening single quote in sed regexp in example 2. I can't edit it, since changes must be at least 6 characters. Could you fix it in case someone will find this useful too?